# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `in` of type `function` supplied to `CSSTransition`, expected `boolean`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import "./SideDrawer.css";

const SideDrawer = (props) => {
  const content = (
    <CSSTransition
      timeout={200}
      in={props.show}
      classNames="slide-in-left"
      unmountOnExit
    >
      <aside className="side-drawer">{props.children}</aside>
    </CSSTransition>
  );

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(content, document.getElementById("drawer-hook"));
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

Im trying to run this code by adding show as a prop to another js file. but it keeps getting me that error. So, any help boys?

Answer (score 0):

I think "in" prop should be an boolean prop, maybe type of your "props.show" is a function.

You can see it on react-transition-group [example](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition)

Comment: I tried man doing it that way. But still I do not get what I want